# Chaining SQL statements while each can work by its own

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Using Python ( or any pseudo code ) I am trying to find a way using `CTE` (or without) to create functions where each query a certain goal, but each can also be the base column for another query.

I am not sure if there is a term for this type of algorithm.

For instance, some users want to *find 5% drop in a curve `'close'` column*, others want to find it over a Simple Moving Average (`sma`) column of that same curve, and others only want the Simple Moving Average.

```
//this can find moving average by its own, or can return a query as base to another

def getquerySMA():
    e = ('''
        SELECT date, date_num, s, close,
        avg(close) OVER (ORDER BY date_num 
        ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as sma
        FROM history
        ''')
    return e //or execute e



//this can find a drop in the curve **on sma column as base**, or on original table

def findDrop(sma):

 e = ('''
    WITH WIN AS (
        SELECT date, date_num, s, close,
        LAG(close,3) OVER (ORDER BY date_num) w0. //*** here the LAG can be used on sma column or on close column based on the sma argument
        FROM {base}
        WHERE s = 'A'
    ), TRD AS(
        SELECT date,date_num, s, close, 100*(close-w0)/close change
        FROM WIN
        WHERE w0 IS NOT NULL
    ), FRST AS(
        SELECT date,date_num, s, close, change,
        LAG(change,1) OVER (ORDER BY date_num) final_lag
        FROM TRD
    )
    SELECT date,date_num, s, close, change, final_lag
    FROM FRST
    WHERE  Abs(change) > 15 AND Abs(final_lag) < 15

    ''')
```

So I would like to find a way to concat the `sma` query string into this query, in a way that I can decide if I want to run the second query where LAG is on `close` column **or on the** `sma` column result.

Comment: Why don't you embed the first query in a sql function that you can call from scratch of from your second query ? How can you decide to run the second query with lag on `close` or on `sma`, is it an input parameter of a function, or ... ?

Answer (score 0):

@baltiturg If all your select fields are independent, you can try constructing the query using the builder pattern.
But if you have dependencies between columns and you need to find out all the dependent columns for a given column, it's a topological sort problem, and the solution is Khan's Algorithm. Hard code the list of all columns in an array(Which are nodes in the problem) and dependents of each node in a dictionary(which are the edges in the problem).

Sample Ruby code for query construction using builder pattern: https://gist.github.com/dheecoder/7aa413a0ccca98c2e02983c06baea381

Comment: @baltiurg I could add much detailed explanation if you are in a need of it.

Comment: Thanks very much, yea the second query will be based on a column created in the first one (sma). Trying to read about what you just offered, what about a sub query? like sending a sub query? this will work but very dirty and messy. Will be happy to see some pseudo code of what you meant.

Comment: @baltiturg If you can find some advantages in subqueries over joins in your query, you can go for it. Also, I have added the sample code in the answer. I hope this helps.